# Get attribute value in product view page

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute, view

I want to to display attribute value in Product view page. [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-arjun.html)

I'm trying following code :

```
echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
```

or

```
$_attribute_code = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($_attribute->getAttributeId())->getAttributeCode();
```

I replaced attribute code : "**brand**" in above code and using :

```
 echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getbrand();
```

or

```
 $_brand = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($_attribute->getAttributeId())->type();
```

but it's not working : `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeId() on a non-object in`

Please help me to find where i am missing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are in the product view page, in the `catalog/product/view.phtml` there is an instance of the product model usually called `$_product`.

From this variable you have access to all the attribute products by the getter methods.

If you want to display the value on the page you have to use the echo php command.

```
echo "Brand is " . $_product->getData("attribute_code");
or
echo "Brand is " . $_product->getAttributeCode();
```

If you have a "dropdown" attribute type `getData()` and it will return the `id` of the option. If you need the label of the dropdown you can use the

```
echo "Brand is " . $_product->getAttributeText("attribute_code");
```

Comment: seems i am missing somewhere. please check view.phtml : http://pastebin.com/RjEnsHwR please search for "brnad" in the code.

Comment: you're missing the php echo instruction that will "echo" the text on the screen, I've edited my answer

Comment: And for a multiselect?

Comment: Thanks for the getData() :)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your quest correctly you are trying to get attribute value on the product page.

This should give you the result:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

Assumption `$_product` is an object and already initiated before calling the above code.

Check some more info regarding attribute:

```
/**
 * get attribute collection
 */
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');
/**
 * get attribute type
 */
$attribute->getAttributeType();
/**
 * get attribute Label
 */
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
/**
 * get attribute default value
 */
$attribute->getDefaultValue();
/**
 * check if the attribute is visible
 */
$attribute->getIsVisible();
/**
 * check if the attribute is required
 */
$attribute->getIsRequired();
/**
 * get attribute value
 */
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute();
```

More reading: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/

**[UPDATE]**

To get brand in product view page you have to do this:

1. Go to admin then catalog > attribute > manage attribute
2. Then search `manufacturer` and edit that
3. Set `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to **YES**

This will make sure it is visible in the frontend.

Comment: seems i am missing somewhere. please check view.phtml : http://pastebin.com/RjEnsHwR please search for "brnad" in the code.

Comment: To get brand you should call `manufacturer` instead. So it is `$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');`

Comment: sorry, i tried that . but it did't worked me....

Comment: You need to set `Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` to Yes to be able to show up in frontend. Have you done this?

Comment: yes, i done that before , but i wanted the attribute value in some other place, so i was struggling for that ....

Comment: @AdarshKhatri How to get product attributes. I am using $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();  but wrong values values shown, what is the exact declaration?

Comment: @zus are you trying to get the list of attributes but not the attribute value of a product?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri How to correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

On product view page

```
<?php 

echo "brand is " . $_product->getAttributeCode();

?>
```

Comment: There is no `getAttributeCode` method on the product model. You may have confused it with the attribute model.